# Excel - How to check if hidden rows exits using python

Tags: python

i am looking for a python function to check if any of the excel rows are hidden or not ?

i have a folder with 30 excels , need to check if  some of the rows are hidden in any of the sheets.

Comment: xlrd.sheet.Rowinfo.hidden  working fine thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XLRD](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) Python module to parse XLS files. To check if cell is hidden you can use **Rowinfo** and **Colinfo** classes and their **hidden** field.

[Read more here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966)

Comment: The link is not valid. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Hi I have not been using this for long time so I'm not able to provide example easily but here you have [snapshot from wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131030003436/https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) of the link

Answer (score 1):

Try the following if your file is an .xls file:

```
    import xlrd
    workbook = 'path to your xls file'
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook, formatting_info=True)
    ws = wb.sheet_names()

    test_sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(ws[0])

    #assuming my 4th row is hidden
    row_state = test_sheet.rowinfo_map[3].hidden

    #assuming my 3rd column  is hidden
    col_state = test_sheet.colinfo_map[2].hidden
```

Setting formatting_info=True is important.